# Getting a error called ''Class 'Database\Seeders\App\Models\Product' not found'' in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am currently learning to create a shop cart in laravel.But when running the seed command im getting a error called  **Class 'Database\Seeders\App\Models\Product' not found**

First i created the database migration called 'Product' and added those.

```
 public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('imagepath');
        $table->string('card-title');
        $table->text('card-text');
        $table->integer('card-price');
        
    });
}
```

Then i created a seeder called 'ProductTableSeeder'.
After that i defined all of them in a array in **Product.php** which is in **app\Models**

```
class Product extends Model
```

{

```
protected $fillable = ['imagepath','card-title','card-text','card-price'];
```

}

Then i pass the array in 'ProductTableSeeder'

```
public function run()
{
   $product= new App\Models\Product ([
    'imagepath'=>'assets/img/plants/7.jpg',
    'card-title'=>'Books',
    'card-text'=>'aaaaaaaa',
    'card-price'=>'500',
   ]);
   $product->save();
```

Finally in 'DatabaseSeeder' i called the ProductTableSeeder to execute once i run the seed command

```
 public function run()
{
    $this->call(ProductTableSeeder::class);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$product= new App\Models\Product ([
```

This should be like this;

```
$product= new \App\Models\Product ([
```

Check it out on your `ProductTableSeeder.php` file

Comment: Thank you so much!. Sorry to bother you for such a stupid question xD

Comment: It's not a stupid question :) Your code would work in most places, but seeders do not have a namespace by default, which is why you need the first `\\`

Comment: @TimLewis Thank u